# Bodhipakkhiya: Panca Indriya versus Panca Bala

Tags: enlightenment

In the *Bodhipakkhiya* (the 37 factors of enlightenment) are mentioned the *Panca Indriya* and the *Panca Bala*. Both sets have the same factors: *saddha*; *virya*; *sati*; *samadhi* and *panna*. Why are those sets separately mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the faculty ([Indriya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indriya)) to exert the strength ([Bala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Strengths)). Say you are a person generally strong in saddha you can use this fact to apply saddha for your spiritual development.

Answer (score 1):

Maurice Walshe's note in his "[Long Discourses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004124JKK)" says:

> "[note 1150]..These five ‘faculties’ (faith, etc. as 6 (vi)) become powers (i.e. unshakeable by their opposites) from First Path (Stream Entry) onwards.."